# express 4 router with express.Router(), how to get a global database connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

how can pass a global variable in node from a file to a module ?
I'm trying with a db variable that is a database mongo connection.I copy the contents of file for the connections that i was trying to do, but did not work, have no errors in console; just in my browser got error 500.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var accounts = require('./routes/accounts');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);


app.use('/accounts', accounts);

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404 - Not Found');
});

// custom 500 page
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(500);
    res.send('500 - Server Error');
});

var mongoUtil = require( './mongoUtil');

mongoUtil.connectToServer( function( err ) {


    app.listen(app.get('port') , function() {
        console.log('Express started in ' + app.get('env') +
            ' mode on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') +
            '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
    });
} );
```

mongoUtils.js

```
var MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

var dbclass = module.exports = {

    db : null,

    connectToServer: function( callback ) {

        var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/crm1';

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if(err) throw err;

            console.log("Connected successfully to server");


            dbclass.db  = db;


        });


    },

    getDb: function() {
        return dbclass.db;
    }
};
```

/router/accounts.js

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();
var db =  .... ??? ;


router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    findDocuments(db, function() {
        db.close();
    });

});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('POST handler for /dogs route.');
});



var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    // Get the documents collection
    var collection = db.collection('accounts');
    // Find some documents
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {

        console.log("Found the following records");
        console.log(docs);
        callback(docs);

    });


}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: *Awful way*: Use `globals`. *Ugly way*: attach your db to `req` in a middleware, use `req.db` in your router. *Not so bad way but not good yet*: make `account.js` export a constructor/generator that take the `db` as parameters.

Comment: mmm one week i'm struggling with this, despite read tutorials and books. export/generator in ES6 ?

Comment: Basically, you don't export the router, but a `getRouter(db)` function, that itself return the router.

Comment: but in express4 i must to do:  var accounts = require('./routes/accounts'); then ,  app.use('/accounts', accounts); that need to change it too ?

Comment: Yes, you will either need to connect to your db first, then `require('routes/accounts')(db)`, or connect first and `app.use('/accounts', accounts(db));`

Comment: look at the final solution in the second block of my question

Comment: What you can do is post your final code as a answer, it prevent peoples looking at your question to think it is a wall of text, and allow them to upvote your solution independently of your question. You can also accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewrittenthe code following @DrakaSAN ideas; my code had errors, i've changed in a betther way:

app.js

```
let express = require('express');

let app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

let dbMongo = require( './db/dbMongoNative');


dbMongo.init ( function( error ) {

    if (error)
        console.error(error);

    let accounts = require('./routesMongoNative/accounts');
    accounts.init();

    app.use('/accounts', accounts.getRouter());

    app.get('/',function(req, res) {
        res.send('hello');
    });


    app.use(function(req, res) {
        res.type('text/plain');
        res.status(404);
        res.send('404 - Not Found');
    });

    // custom 500 page
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.type('text/plain');
        res.status(500);
        res.send('500 - Server Error');
    });

    app.listen(app.get('port') , function() {
        console.log('Express started in ' + app.get('env') +
            ' mode on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') +
            '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
    });
} );
```

/db/dbMongoNative.js

```
var MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient;

module.exports.init =  function (callback) {

    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/crm1';

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (error, db) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        console.log("Connected successfully to server");

        module.exports.db = db;

        console.log('end connect');
        callback (error);

    });
};
```

/routesMongoNative/accounts.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var dbMongo  = require( '../db/dbMongoNative' );

let db = dbMongo.db;  // connection was done before in app

let findAll = function(res, db ) {
    db.collection('accounts').find( {}).toArray( function( error, result ) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.json(result);

    });
};

function init() {
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        findAll(res, db );

    });
}


function getRouter() {
    return router;
}

module.exports = {
    init: init,
    getRouter: getRouter
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A working and not awful way to do this is to not export the router directly, but a generator for it. Multiples syntax are possibles for the generator, I ve chosen to show you a example using a similar pattern than the one you used for your `MongoUtils`:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var mongoUtil = require( './mongoUtil');

mongoUtil.connectToServer( function( err ) {
    var accounts = require('./routes/accounts');
    accounts.init(mongoUtils.getDb());
    app.use('/accounts', accounts.getRouter());

    app.use(function(req, res) {
        res.type('text/plain');
        res.status(404);
        res.send('404 - Not Found');
    });

    // custom 500 page
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.type('text/plain');
        res.status(500);
        res.send('500 - Server Error');
    });

    app.listen(app.get('port') , function() {
        console.log('Express started in ' + app.get('env') +
            ' mode on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') +
            '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
    });
} );
```

/router/accouts.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

function init(db) {
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        findDocuments(db, function() {
            db.close();
        });

    });

    router.post('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('POST handler for /dogs route.');
    });

    var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
        // Get the documents collection
        var collection = db.collection('accounts');
        // Find some documents
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
            console.log("Found the following records");
            console.log(docs);
            callback(docs);
        });
    }
}

function getRouter() {
    return router;
}


module.exports = {
    init: init,
    getRouter: getRouter
};
```

Comment: my code had errors, your ideas for to solve this is ok; i've correct the code and  i've improved it. to see the solution under my question.